# How To Get Class Variables into Static Methods?

Tags: python, class, static

So I Have `main.py`:

```py
import os
import json

class Create_project:
    def __init__(self,version):
        self.version = version        
    
    @staticmethod
    def Name(cls):
        project_name = cls
    
    @staticmethod
    def Res(cls):
        if cls == True:
           os.chdir('Project')
           os.mkdir(f"gyy_RP")
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Create_project()
```

& `project.py`:

```py
import neptune_lib

neptune_lib.Create_project("1.16.210")
neptune_lib.Create_project.Name("My Addon")
neptune_lib.Create_project.Res(True)
```

I Want To Create A Directory Named By The User , But I Failed To get `project_name` to The `Res` Function.

So How do i get `project_name` into The`Res`Function ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use staticmethods? Just make everything into class methods and you can get it easily.

Edit:
Change your code to

```
import os
import json

class Create_project:
    def __init__(self,version):
        self.version = version
        self.project_name = None        
    
    def Name(self, cls):
        self.project_name = cls
    
    def Res(self, cls):
        if cls == True:
           os.chdir('Project')
           os.mkdir(str(self.project_name))
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Create_project()
```

And call it with:

```
import neptune_lib

a = neptune_lib.Create_project("1.16.210")
a.Name("My Addon") 
a.Res(True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! i've been struggling 